# Has an idol been clearly defined as to what is an Idol that makes it Avodah Zarah?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

Has the Hebrew word for an "idol" been clearly defined as to what is an Idol and what is not?

Comment: For what purposes? I imagine there may be multiple definitions in differing contexts (though maybe not).

Comment: For judging an object to be an Idol .

Comment: @msh210 Perhaps for purposes relating to [tag:avodah-zarah]?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the body.

Comment: @DoubleAA does it now?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Ali, re the requirement to destroy it? re the ban on worshiping it? re the ban on owning it? re the ban on deriving benefit from it? re the process of 'nullifying' it? For what purposes are you asking? There may be different answers depending.

Comment: @msh210 all of them , how can a definition of idol changed based on how it is used , doesnt idols have intrinsic qualities that make them soo?

Comment: Ali, I'll venture a guess that _idol_ is not a word that appears in any classic Jewish sources: they're mostly in Hebrew (though in some other languages too). So you're really looking not for a definition of _idol_ at all but for a definition of a Hebrew word corresponding to _idol_. And it's certainly possible (though I don't know) that there's more than one such word depending on context, or that such a word has more than one meaning depending on context (much as _r'shus harabim_ has very different meanings for _nezek bor_ and for _haavara arba amos_).

Comment: @msh210 and for _safek tuma_... As for Hebrew words consider צלם פסל מסכה or צורה

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is defined but as often occurs in Jewish law, there's a tremendous amount of nuance from case-to-case. But I will simply point out that one can theologically violate "worshipping something other than God" without necessary rendering a specific object an "idol." (E.g. if someone walks onto my yard and bows down to my apple tree and tries to worship it, he is committing idolatry, but he had no ownership of my tree and therefore didn't render it an "idol." I can still use that tree. Versus a tree that was planted for the purposes of worship is prohibited from use.)

The Talmud's tractate of "Avoda Zarah" (foreign worship) devotes its third chapter to this, what's called an idol and what's more likely a decoration. E.g. a rule of thumb had been that a Greek/Roman statue of a person holding a globe, staff, or bird was likely actually idolized, whereas a statue of a person holding something else (e.g. a [torch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue_of_liberty)?) was probably just symbolic. Similarly there's the story of a Greek bathhouse with an image of [Aphrodite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphrodite) on it; a rabbi still used the bathhouse. Asked how he could do so,
he explained (after exiting the bathhouse, as we don't discuss Torah in a bathhouse): "you Greeks didn't say, let's build a bathhouse to glorify Aphrodite. You said, let's build a bathhouse because we want one, and we'll put an Aphrodite on it to glorify the bathhouse!"

Later works such as Shulchan Aruch discuss many more cases (e.g. the Hispanic-products aisle in many supermarkets contains candles with pictures of saints on the glass jar -- while I strongly recommend buying regular candles instead, if this was the only candle available, a rabbi should ask -- was that truly made for the purpose of worship, or was that made by Acme Candle Co. who would just as happily put SpongeBob Squarepants on the jar if it sells better?)

Comment: Good andwer You have not addressed the issue of people making the Idol as a medium of worship to one God.

Comment: @shalom it wasn't a picture if Aphrodite it was an actual statue if I remember correctly

Comment: @knowit Not sure how that's necessary for this question.