# Can photographs be considered idols?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, pictures, kavana-intent

Can photographs of people be considered idols? Is it the kavanot that the viewer ascribes that is important or is it inherent in a 2D image of a face?

Comment: I read that the Satmar Rav z"l advised his Chasidim to burn photographs in their possession. If this is true, I don't know if he thought this was the letter of the law, or an extra act of piety.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26841

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29031/759

Comment: Duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26841/is-it-allowed-to-make-paintings-of-living-creatures ?

Answer (score 5):

A photograph can be considered an idol if there's someone who's worshipped it as one, same as most anything else. If it was made by a (halachically non-Jewish) religionist as an idol of his religion's, it's considered such even before it's worshipped (*Shulchan Aruch*, *YD* 139:1). Therefore, certain pictures should be assumed to be idols absent knowledge to the contrary (*SA* 141:1–3); which pictures that rule applies to depends on the time and place (*Shach* 141:17, *Beur Hag'ra* :18). But there's nothing inherent in photographs of people that makes them all into idols. As always, for practical questions, contact your rabbi rather than relying on what you read here.