# Pictures of rabbis in the living room

Tags: halacha, rabbis, avodah-zarah, pictures

Are there any poskim prohibiting hanging Pictures of Rabbis in ones house? Lots of people do it but I never understood why this is not prohibited due to too much kavod for human being, which is close to Avoda Zara.

Isn't it?

Comment: Duplicate/related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33965/can-photographs-be-considered-idols

Comment: Are these rabbis relatives?

Comment: Is this a reference to pictures of the Lubavitcher rebbe?

Comment: @Lee I would say that this isn't a duplicate, since this specifically addresses the line about honoring a rav and worshipping him, or using him as an intercessor, which isn't addressed in this question

Comment: umm, would having a picture of your father be "too much kavod for [a] human being"? If not, neither is a picture of your teacher. You have to respect your teacher more than your father. (Similar to http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=33&format=text)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Most people don't have pictures of their parents around due to kavod

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a perfectly legit question and phrased in clear language...

Comment: What's the problem with this question? Maybe the answer is there are no problems, but there's certainly a valid question in here.

Comment: Shimon, you asked a valid question. I have suspicions but no evidence as to why it was down voted.

Comment: I downvoted because it reads like a rant (your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?” to quote the help center). A more neutral question ("Does hanging pictures of Rabbis in one's house create issues of too much kavod for a human being, which (based on X) is close to Avoda Zara? Do any poskim speak about this question and address this concern?") - I would have up-voted. Without a reason provided to think it is Avoda Zara, I would have left it alone.

Comment: The chida and the divrei malkiel both frown upon placing pictures of human faces on ones wall. The chida says that it is problematic when bowing to the sides after shmona esreh for it looks like one is praying to them.

Comment: Why do you think that showing too much respect for people is close avoda zara? Respect is respect, and worship is worship. A lot of respect isn't worship; it is a lot of respect.